# How do I abstract this executeQuery() function to accommodate all return types?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql

Our GraphQL resolver are sometimes returning `result.rows` and sometimes returning `result.rows[0]` depending on the use case.

in order to reduce some of the clutter that currently exists in the resolvers of manually querying the database using the pool connection every single time, I've decided to write a `executeQuery()` function that uses `pg` for types and would get the `query.text` and `query.values` as arguments and return back the result. the problem is, is that it is still not abstracted well enough to know when to return `result.rows` and when to return `result.rows[0]` I've tried to handle that conditionally using `rowCount` when it is either `1` for `result.rows[0]` and if it's `>1` to return `result.rows` as a whole.

I'm gonna put a short overview of my resolver and the function thus far down below.

```
    const executeQuery = async <T>(
        pool: Pool, 
        query: string,
        values: QueryValues,
    ): Promise<ExecuteQueryResult<T>> => {
        const result = await pool.query(query, values)
        if (result.rowCount != 1 && result.rowCount != 0) {
            return result.rows
        }

        return result.rows[0]
    }
```

```
// before executeQuery 
        async Plugins(obj, _args, ctx: UserContext) {
            const {
                text,
                values,
            } = sql`select * from company_plugins where company_id = ${obj.id}`
            const result = await ctx.db.query({
                text,
                values,
            })
            return result.rows
        },

// after executeQuery 
        async Plugins(obj, _args, ctx: UserContext) {
            const {
                text,
                values,
            } = sql`select * from company_plugins where company_id = ${obj.id}`
            const result = await ctx.executeQuery(text, values) 
            return result
        },
```

I have some types that expects an empty array `[]` so if Plugins were to be empty, it expects it to be `[]` rather than null. so if `executeQuery` is not well abstracted it would return the first element of the array and it would be `null` and therefore result in a failing test.

Here is the type of `Plugins` in `Company`

```
    Plugins: [CompanyPlugin]
```

Comment: Just use two functions, `executeQueryArray` and `executeQueryArray`? What further abstraction are you looking for?

Comment: could you provide an example for both, please ?

Comment: You've already given them in your question. "*[One is] returning `result.rows` and [the other is] returning `result.rows[0]` depending on the use case.*"